# Drawing a simple anti-aliased stickman in OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I would like to draw a simple 2D stickman on the screen. I also want it to be anti-aliased.

The problem is that I want to use a bones system, which will be written after I would know how to draw the stickman itself based on the joints positions. This means I can't use sprites - I want my stickman to be fully controlable in the code.

It would be great if it will be possible to draw curves too.

Drawing a 3D stickman using a model would also be great if not better. The camera will be positioned like it's 2D, but I would still have depth. The problem is that I only have experience in Maya, and exporting and vertex weighting of the model in OpenGL seems like a mess...

I tried to find libraries for 2D anti-aliased drawing or enable multi-sampling and draw normally, but I had no luck. I also tried to use OpenGL's native anti-aliasing but it seems deprecated and the line joins are bad...

I don't want it to be too complicated because, well, it shouldn't be - it's just the first part of my program, and it's drawing a **stickman**...

I hope you guys can help me, I'm sure you know better than me :)

Comment: have you written any code? have you tried something? we are not here to write the code for you, we can help you with specific problems you're having though.

Comment: I did, but it's useless. I don't need you to write any code for me, I just need a direction, because right now I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 4):

You could enable GL_SMOOTH. To check if you device supports your required line width for smooth lines, you can use glGet(GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE);

If you want your code to be generic, you can also use antialiased textures.
Take a look at this link

http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/advanced/advanced97/notes/node62.html

Comment: Although it looks like i'm gonna need to implement this method myself, it's really my last option - I'm searching for something like cairo, that can be used for games. I don't need super quality, just basic anti-aliasing and integration with OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get antialiasing is use GL library which knows how to get antialiased GL context, for [example](http://adrianboeing.blogspot.com/2010/01/antialiasing-multisampling-opengl-with.html), SDL. As of stickman, you can draw him with colored polygons.

Comment: This example uses multisampling, which is not supported by all cards (mine doesn't support it too), so I need something more generic, but thanks!

Comment: @crazyspacemonkey: I'd be very surprised if your graphics card doesn't support multisampling/full screen antialiasing. Even my 1999 GeForce2 can do some FSAA.

Comment: I have Intel GMA X3000, I tried to enable it but I couldn't since the GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB wasn't in the list of extensions that I got from wglGetExtensionsStringARB. If there's something I don't see here... :)

Comment: It even has shader model 4.0! I suppose you just need fresh drivers. Or really go with textures.